# My requirement is In android I have 4 dynamic columns of images in which there shoud be a empty column after second column

Tags: android

Please suggest which is the best approach to follow. I tried with Grid View but i was not able to get a empty column

Comment: means in the 3rd column you dont want to show anything ...right?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a `GridView` (should work fine for your case), you could [use a GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html). I would not advise this if you are going to have a lot of `ImageView`s, because you will need the recycling abilities of the `GridView`.

In the case of `GridLayout`, you can create the base `GridLayout`, set to 5 columns and use `GridLayout.addView(View, LayoutParams)` to append new `ImageView`s. When you are on the second column add a [Space](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) view.

Some simple pseudocode:

```
for(int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
    ImageView imageView = getImageViewUsingList(i);

    if((i % 5) % 2 == 1) {
        gridLayout.addView(new Space(), layoutParams);
    } else {
        gridLayout.addView(imageView, layoutParams);
    }
}
```